# How to insert facebook type pagination in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to insert pagination in my flutter app, which will look exactly like the ine in facebook. I have read about `infinite_scroll_pagination` package, but I was not able to achieve it. Can anyone help me on this please?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you should use [refreshindicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RefreshIndicator-class.html) as shown in official flutter docs.

```
RefreshIndicator(
    onRefresh: _onRefresh,
    child: ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
      children: _listData.map((i) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text("Item $i"),
        );
      }).toList(),
    )
);
```

[image]